# Shared Element Transition Between Activity And CustomDialog

Tags: java, android, transition, shared-element-transition

I was wondering if there is any way to implement the **Shared Element Transiition** Between an **Activity** and a **CustomDialog** that I made. I know how it is implemented between 2 activities but wondering if this is possible between activity and dialog (JAVA).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your own style for shared element transition like this,

```
<style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Panel">
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/MyAnimation.Window</item>
</style>

<style name="MyAnimation.Window" parent="@android:style/Animation.Activity">
    <item name="android:windowEnterTransition">@anim/anim_in</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitTransition">@anim/anim_out</item>
</style>
```

- for the anim_in.xml
  [anim_in.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5mcv.png)
- for the anim_out.xml
  [anim_out.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7v2y.png)

and then put it on Dialog, like this:

```
dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this, R.style.MyCustomTheme);
```

hope can help you

Comment: Thanks for the answer, when I try it I'll get back to you

Comment: I hope you can vote up if it help you, Thanks